# missing equal sign in oracle for an update query

Tags: sql, oracle

It's a simple update query, but I don't know why it says missing equal sign.
Plz Help.

```
update jv_news 
set upper(application) = 'IPT' ,
    upper(title) = 'MR_C1_TUPDATE' ,
    upper  (visible) = 'N'
where ID=15
```

Comment: You can't apply a function on the column to be updated. `upper(application) = 'IPT'` does not make any sense. Just use `application = 'IPT'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is `upper` in the statement? You should write `update` statement like this:

```
update jv_news 
set application = 'IPT' ,
    title = 'MR_C1_TUPDATE' ,
    visible = 'N'
where ID=15
```

Comment: Thank you , i dint knew dat we cannot use any function over a column to be updated!

Comment: @lucky: think about what a function does: it takes the value of a column and returns a different value. How can you "update" a value that is not stored anywhere.

Comment: Well, you could certainly do that in the `WHERE` clasue, but not in the `SET` clause. Since, Oracle expects `COLUMN NAME` to be updated and not an `EXPRESSION`.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use function over a column to be updated in the `SET` clause. Since, Oracle expects `COLUMN NAME` to be updated and not an `EXPRESSION`.

If you are not sure about the `CASE` of the input values, and if you want the query to always `UPDATE` with `UPPER CASE`, then you can specify `UPPER` on the values itself.

```
update jv_news 
set application = UPPER('ipt') ,
    title = UPPER('mr_C1_TUPdate') ,
    visible = UPPER('n')
where ID=15
```

Thus, you need not worry about the case of the input values.